# Pyplot: fit a patch (circle) to screen

Tags: matplotlib

I am drawing a circle with the following code. I have Pyplot set to make the figure take up the whole screen. When it was a smaller screen, it would appear as a circle, but fullscreen makes it warped. How can I keep the circle plot a 1:1 ratio? (I.e., I want to keep the circle centered and looking the same, with the black background filling in the rest of the screen.)

Thanks!

```
#Necessary imports
import matplotlib as plt
plt.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Initialize/define stuff
circle = plt.Circle((0.5, 0.5), 0.2, color='white')
fig, ax = plt.subplots() # note we must use plt.subplots, not plt.subplot
plt.axis('off')
figManager = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
figManager.full_screen_toggle()

#Display
ax.add_artist(circle)
fig.set_facecolor("black")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: @IoBE: Respectfully, I appreciate the utility of parsimony on StackOverflow, but I think this question is unique because: (a) it is asked in a different way (the other one has a lot more jargon and isn't immediately comprehensible to me); (b) the garnered solution from Bazingaa is a lot more straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify an equal aspect ratio for your x and y axis since by default both your x and y-axis have equal limits. Specifically, you can do

```
ax.add_artist(circle)
ax.set_aspect('equal') # <----------- Added here
fig.set_facecolor("black")
```

[image]